# How to indirectly use FCL 4.0 code from a .NET 2.0 assembly?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, t4

I'm trying to slicken the use of T4 generation in a project I'm writing which unfortunately has to target .NET 2.0 for the customer, but I can't seem to either avoid using FCL 4.0 libraries or to find a way VS will let me access the types in an assembly targeting 4.0 from one targeting 2.0.

The idea is to declare a `T4Attribute` that can be used to decorate a partial type in the consuming project. Extra code for the type will then be generated by T4 according to the  details of the attribute. As an example, most of the boilerplate parts of the standard dispose pattern could be added to a type just by using a one-line attribute decoration.

I'm deriving my own custom `TextTransformation` to support this, but since I have VS2010 I can't install the VS2005/8 SDK, only the VS2010 one, which means the `TextTransformation` I'm using is in a .NET 4.0 DLL (Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.10.0). So the attribute is in the same DLL, and when I try to reference that DLL from the consuming project, it can only see the types if both are targeting the same framework version. As soon as the project is 2.0 and the library is 4.0, VS no longer finds the referenced type or namespace.

I guess it thinks that since the application will fire up CLRv2 to run, it wouldn't be able to run code in a v4 DLL (which might use `dynamic` etc). Fair enough but in reality the types in the library will only ever be seen on the dev PC by a T4 template scanning the project for those `T4Attribute`s telling it to generate code - and I assume the T4 engine in VS2010 runs under CLRv4. The attributes won't even be compiled into release builds.

I'm still at the bottom of the learning curve on this. Am I doing it wrong, is there a much easier way, and if not, is there a way around my problem? Could I somehow obtain the older VisualStudio DLLs despite having the wrong VS version?

Comment: Updating an *eight* year old version of the framework is a no-brainer solution.  Struggling with being innovative in a company that's too stuck in its ways is something you cannot get help with here.  Have a look at careers.

Comment: Edited to clarify that the need for v2.0 is due to limitations at the customer end. I'm guessing the problem is not that I'm targeting an _obsolete_ .NET version but that I'm targeting _any_ version earlier than the one under which the installed VS SDK runs?

Comment: An idea; does it help to specify the version of C# to use in the template directive? http://www.olegsych.com/2008/02/t4-template-directive/

Comment: It is a strange setup that you have to reference the assembly of your development tool in your production code (to have the attribute). I have also a bad feeling about the order of compilations and code generation. If you have to use an attribute to mark the partial class, then this partial class must be compiled without the generated parts first for the templating, then the templating generates the missing partial part to complete the class. But what if the assembly cannot be compiled without the generated part first? (e.g. you need the generated code in another class in the same dll?)

Comment: @Fule: No, the C# version is a compiler feature, not a .NET feature. Its effect is on the interpretation of the template code much later on when it is transformed. -- @Tz_: Not an issue, as I'm using the VS object model (`EnvDTE`) rather than any kind of transform-on-build. The project is scanned and code generated without needing to start a build. I agree it is an odd setup - the advantage is that I get full design-time support for my tool, completely free, but I do wonder if it will give me problems further down the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two assemblies. First, targeting .NET 2.0 to define the T4Attribute you described and second, targeting .NET 4.0 to define the custom TextTransformation. That way, you can reference the first assembly from both your product code and from the second assembly for code generation purposes.

Comment: That's reassuring - after being less than enthused by the earlier responses, I spent my evening trying exactly that and have found no problems so far except some minor complication with NUnit and duplicate declarations, but no showstoppers. Your answer exactly describes the arrangement I ended up having to use to make it work. I've just finished testing a proof of concept, it runs perfectly and I agree this is the best (and only) workaround likely to come up - thanks!